# How can I read and separate txt file containing character and two column of numbers?

Tags: numbers, character

I have a *.txt file containing character and two column of numbers. How can I read the file and just pick up numbers of column? In fact I want to plot the numbers in first column vs those in the second columns, but I cant separate the numbers from characters. My txt files appear as below.
thanks a lot.

```
Temperature: Not acquired
Spectrometer Type: S2000
ADC Type: ADC1000USB
Number of Pixels in File: 2048
Graph Title: 
>>>>>Begin Spectral Data<<<<<
229.20  0.000
229.57  0.000
229.94  0.037
230.31  0.047
230.68  -0.027
231.05  0.027
etc ....
```

Comment: What platform/language are you using. Can you show us what you have tried so fat.

Comment: I use MATLAB.  I tried "textread", "textscan", "importdata" , but non of them work properly. I have an error when I use "textread" for example. The error is: Trouble reading floating point number from file (row 1, field 1) ==> OOIBase32 Version 2.0.5.5 Data